# Couchbase retrieving relational docs in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-ottoman

I am still debating which way to go and possibly store certain information in its own doc. so for example the customer can have addresses with each address would be its own doc and then in the customer doc there would be an array of ref keys stored  under addresses. The benefit would be i could update these docs simply based on the key value vs having to get the customer doc first, finding the array index of the address and then either modify the whole doc or go and use subdoc to replace the content of the array with the index.
Where i am stuck is how to retrieve those referenced subdoc's. is N1QL the only way to go or does the KV API offer a way to do this short of retrieving the whole customer doc, then looping thru address array and retrieving all referenced docs that way. I know Ottoman offers something like that but i am having an issue with the latest version of SDK 2.6 and Ottoman as its not very well maintained. So hopefully someone can share some insight what and why its the best way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rely on key/value, then you'll need to do the multiple lookup as you've described. I'm not very familiar with Ottoman: it *might* do this for you, but behind the scenes it will still be multiple key/value operations and/or N1QL.

With N1QL, you can perform JOINs, but again, behind the scenes it's going to eventually be pulling documents out by key/value. It just does those extra steps for you. Direct key/value is always going to be the fastest route.

If you are still in the process of deciding whether to split the data amongst multiple documents or "denormalize" the data into a single doc, one thing you should think about is how often you're going to access customer+addresses together and how often you're going to customer/access separately. If you're reading/writing customer+address often, consider putting it in one document. Otherwise, consider putting it in multiple documents.

The third option is to store it both places, or rather "cache" the address data in the customer document. This is tricky, because it could get out of sync if you're not careful. So make sure it's worth it before you go down that road.